# How to limit git bash cli access to one private repo and restrict commits to remaining git world?

Tags: azure, github, gitlab, git-bash, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to setup a Azure Virtual Desktop (AVD) to have certain users to login to it and do their work. We do use git. Git Bash is installed on our AVD Windows 10.  How can I limit users to only push their code to our 1 private git repo and how to restrict users from pushing code to public or their personal repos from git bash cli?

Please let me know if you want me to provide more details.

Note:- we are not trying to restrict our engineers from cloning their personal code or public code to our AVD's local. we only want to restrict push activity i.e; allow push to our private repo only. In generic terminology, Downloading(cloning) files is fine, but we want to restrict uploading (push) files alone.

Comment: Why not just firewall the AVDs off from making connections outside of the network resources they require for their work? Generaly in an enterprise environment you should be adhering to the principle of least privilege, anyway (at a network level in addition to an application level)

Comment: Extremely relevant from Software Engineering.SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/377624/35862

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't provide a way to restrict what repositories a user may access.  In order to restrict users from pushing to remotes other than the one you want, you'll need to use standard network mechanisms (e.g., firewalling and IP restrictions) to prevent users from accessing resources you don't want them to have access to.  Note that if your code is also hosted on one of these sites, then there is no effective way to solve this problem.

You may very well be tempted to try to use a proxy or a TLS MITM device to sniff network connections, but my overwhelming experience is that these tools do not understand the basics of HTTP and very frequently break Git.  You are strongly advised not to do this.

I will point out that in general, most developers expect to have access to shell configuration and editor files when working, and if you're trying to really restrict the ability for users to clone this data from their own GitHub repository, then you're basically being really hostile to developers, which people will resent, and your hiring and retention will be correspondingly impacted.  There are ways to have effective controls without having everything locked down, and I strongly recommend implementing the least restrictive policies you can that still meet your organization's security and compliance goals.

Comment: I like your third paragraph. Understanding how to implement good security also means taking into consideration the effects of security. If a security implementation affects a developer's productivity, then there is a cost impact. Sometimes that impact can be the loss of developers who feel that are not trusted and respected to be professionals.

Comment: I do agree with 3rd paragraph. I am not trying to restrict users from cloning their personal code or public code to our AVD's local. we  only want to restrict push activity i.e; allow push to our private repo only. In generic terminology, Downloading(cloning) files is fine, we want to restrict uploading (push) files alone.

Comment: I don't see the problem with pushing a branch with changes to your local dotfiles repository.  I've kept a `work` branch in my dofiles (e.g., with a change in email) for a long time.  Everything about my answer stands about the technical capability of this and that this approach is overly restrictive.